# Which is better practice in regexp?

Tags: regex

So, I am writing a short (and simple) regular expression, but I can think of two *possible* ways to do it. They both seem like good conventions, but I am not sure which one is better.

What I want to achieve with this pattern (ordered hierarchically):

- Speed
- Readability
- Sexyness

The regexp needs to match for one of two characters(let's say they are `#` and `~`) at the beginning of each line:

- `^[#~]`
- `^(#|~)` **Edit:** since `^#|~` didn't do what I wanted it, I corrected it.

I like both of them for different reasons (out of which most are aesthetic reasons); the bonus with the second one is that it's a byte shorter.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's a matter of preference, isn't it?  I tend to like the ^[#~], if only because it is more explicit about the regex's goal, which is to match a single character -- but to each, his own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`^#|~` is not the same as `^[#~]`.** `^#|~` will match a `~` in the middle of the string because `|` has a lower precedence than `^`. The correct way to express that is `^(?:#|~)` or `^(#|~)` if you don't mind about the extra capture group.

Comparing `^[#~]`  to the corrected regex `^(?:#|~)`, I'd say the former totally wins out. (Normally a character class is more efficient than `|` because the latter is less specialized.)

Comment: Oh! You are right! I should have written better tests! Doouh!~

Answer (score 2):

This question has a false premise.  The two provided regex`s are not equivalent on all regex engines.

- `^[#~]`: This will match a `#` or `~` only at the start of a line
- `^#|~`: This will match a `#` at the start of the line and `~` anywhere in the string

Hence i would go with the first as it has the semantics you are looking for.

For Regex's, and really code in general, always prefer the more readable / expressive solution over a perceived performance benefit.  Only make performance choices when a profiler has demonstrated that the performance does indeed matter.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the second one is a byte shorter is, as you can imagine, not exactly relevant. I myself would use the first one (`^[#~]`) since a character class is very easy to understand.
(Also, as mentioned, the second one is not equivalent to the first one. But even if you could rewrite the second one, don't :p)

Comment: Pfft at the comment in the brackets ~

Comment: This website needs some less than extremely serious people.

Comment: I secretly agree with you. :D